# how to mock a closure method

Tags: grails, mocking

I have a service class defined as follows

```
class MyService {

  def otherService;

  def performService( ) {
     Navigator.navigate( retrieveData, { otherService.doSomething(it) } );
  }
  def retrieveData = { Integer offset, Integer maxRows
     DomainObject.list(offset,maxRows);
  }
}

Navigator.navigate( Closure retriever, Closure processor ) {
   def offset=0;
   def batchsize=100;
   while( (data=retriever(offset,batchsize)) ) {
      if(data.size()==0) break;
      data.each { processor(it) }
      offset += data.size();
   }
}
```

In my tests, I would like to mock the retriveData to retrieve mocked objects

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
  def "test retriever"() {
     given:
     service.otherService = Mock(OtherService);
     service.metaClass.retrieveData = { Integer offset, Integer maxRows ->
       if(offset==0) return [ Mock(DomainObject), Mock(DomainObject) ]
       else return []
     }
     when:
     service.performService();

     then:
     2 * otherService.doSomething(_);
  }
}
```

It turns out that the test is not picking up the mocked retrieveData, instead it always picks up the MyService.retrieveData closure, wondering what is the right approach to mock a closure method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it's because `retrieveData` is a field, not a method. Can you try:

```
given:
   ...
   service.retrieveData = { Integer offset, Integer maxRows ->
     ...
   }
```

Comment: Yest that was it, closures seem to behave like fields, so service.retrieveData = { Integer offset, Integer maxRows -> .. } worked